# Can the classifying space of a Lie group be also a Lie group?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, lie-groups, classifying-spaces

How to show a classifying space of a Lie group is also a Lie group or not a Lie group?

For example, $U(1)$ is a Lie group, let us consider the following classifying spaces:

- so $BU(1)=\mathbf{CP}^\infty$ can it be also be a Lie group, but how?
- so $B^2 U(1)=B\mathbf{CP}^\infty$ can it be also be a Lie group, but how?
- so $BSU(2)=\mathbf{HP}^\infty$ can it be also be a Lie group, but how?

Comment: What makes you think any of these things would be Lie groups? (They are not)

Comment: That was what I heard from a lecturer.(!?)

Comment: None of these are Lie groups, especially not the last one.

Comment: so can the classifying space of a Lie group be also a Lie group?

Comment: Yes. $S^1\cong B\mathbb{Z}$ and more generally $T^k\cong B\mathbb{Z}^k$. Not otherwise AFAIK.

Comment: @Tyrone I think any $K(\pi,n)$ for $n>2$ has cohomology in unbounded degrees. So that leaves $n=1$. Being a Lie group implies its fundamental group is abelian. The fundamental group should be torsion free since it it has torsion it will have cohomology in unbounded degrees. I’m not sure how else to narrow it down since there are many torsion free abelian groups.

Comment: I forgot that $\{e\}=B\{e\}$... =(

Answer (score 5):

Let $G$ be a topological group with classifying space $BG$. Suppose that $BG$ supports a group structure. Then there are homotopy equivalences $G\simeq \Omega BG\simeq\Omega^2B^2G$, so $G$ is a double loop space, and in particular supports a homotopy abelian H-space multiplication. However:

> **Theorem**: Let $X$ be a non contractible, connected, finite complex which is a homotopy commutative H-space, then $X$ has the homotopy type of a torus.

This is Theorem 1.1 in John Hubbuck's paper *[On Homotopy Commutative H-spaces](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938369900044)* Top. **8** (1969), 119-126.

Thus the only compact connected Lie groups whose classifying spaces could potentially support a group structure are the tori. Since $BT^k\simeq (BS^1)^k$, to consider these we should study $BS^1$.

Now, it's well-known that $BS^1\simeq K(\mathbb{Z},2)$, and that there are topological groups within this homotopy type. In the comments below I argue that there is in fact an infinite-dimensional Banach Lie group in the homotopy type of $BS^1$. I personally do not consider this a postive answer to your question, but you may be happy with it.

We can also non-compact, non-connected Lie groups. In the connected non-compact world there are examples like $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $T^k\times\mathbb{R}^n$ which meet our critera. However these are essentially the only examples, because in general a noncompact Lie group will deformation retract onto its maximal compact subgroup, and Hubbuck's theorem then gives the same no-go result as before.

In the compact non-connected case there are torsion abelian groups. These do have classifying spaces which are non-compact, non-Lie topological groups (i.e. $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ and other infinite lens spaces).

Finally in the non-compact non-connected case we introduce the torsion free abelian groups $\mathbb{Z}^k$. These groups do provide a positive answer to your question, since, as I mentioned in the comments, you have $B\mathbb{Z}^k\simeq T^k$.

Comment: I was thinking about using this, but I feel like we should allow for non compact manifolds. Do you think this result about the torus holds for noncompact CW complexes that are of bounded dimension?

Comment: Well you can just classify Lie Groups. These are a maximal compact subgroup $\times$ contractible (so in particular are finite complexes up to homotopy).

Comment: I don't know much about infinite-dimensional Lie groups. You can ask if $BS^1\simeq \mathbb{C}P^\infty$ supports a group structure. It's an infintie dimensional manifold which carries an $A_\infty$-structure, but I don't think it has a strict group structure.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12469/group-structure-on-cpinfinty

Comment: @ConnorMalin I couldn't find that thread when I tried. It would seem that Andrew Stacy's suggestion there should work: take a separable, infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space $H$ and let $U(H)$ be its unitary group in the norm topology. This an infinite-dimensional Banach Lie group, and so is the quotient $U(H)/S^1$ by its centre (quote [here](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~preprint/2001/gn2001.pdf)). Since $U(H)$ is contractible in the weak topology $U(H)/S^1$ is a $K(\mathbb{Z},2)\simeq BS^1$. I can't imagine any other case in which such details would line up.

Comment: many thanks --- this helps! Can the classifying space of a Lie group be also a group? (what kind? loop group?)

Comment: @anniemarieheart I rewrote the answer. I did an awful job before, and I hope it's clearer now.